# Why the ApplicationContext and ClasspathXmlApplicationContext are treated as error here

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring and got error in this piece of code; at line 1. 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

  public class DrawingApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Triangle triangle = new Triangle();

            //BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));

            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");  //line1
            Triangle triangle = (Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");
            triangle.draw();

        }

    }
```

The error is shown:- 
ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import statements are missing for ApplicationContext and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

Comment: This is Java 101.....

Answer (score 0):

Include the spring core artifact in the lib or if pom.xml file is available then run the mvn eclipse command by which the artifacts can be resolved